# How to make every thread pass another parameter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, arguments

I'm not 100% sure how to explain this, it's best to see in code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <pthread.h>
#define N 30

using namespace std;

int ZajednickoPolje[50][N];

void *Generiraj(void * i){
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        ZajednickoPolje[*((int*)i)][j]=rand()%50;
}

void *Racunaj(void * i){
    int suma=0;
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        suma=suma+ZajednickoPolje[*((int*)i)][j];
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"Polje"<<*((int*)i)<<" suma = "<<suma<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"Polje"<<*((int*)i)<<" aritm_sredina = "<<float(suma)/N<<endl;
}

int main(){

   int M, i;
   cin>>M;
   pthread_t thr_id[M*2];

    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
   if (pthread_create(&thr_id[i], NULL, Generiraj, &i) != 0) {
      cout<<"Greska pri stvaranju dretve!\n";
      exit(1);
   }

    for(i=M;i<(2*M);i++)
   if (pthread_create(&thr_id[i], NULL, Racunaj, &i) != 0) {
      cout<<"Greska pri stvaranju dretve!\n";
      exit(1);
   }

   for(int i=0;i<(2*M);i++)
   pthread_join(thr_id[i], NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

So, I want in main function to pass variable "i" to functions "Generiraj" and "Racunaj", but it's value is always M*2.
I understand why does that happen, but not sure how to solve it?

Comment: I guess I asked wrong question.. I think that they pass right parameters, but variable "i" stops at M*2, so when I put "cout<<i" I want it to be the number of a thread.

Comment: Stop giving all your variables the same name! What is `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options, the important thing is not to pass a pointer to the same `i` to all threads. This is one option, create dynamic storage for the integer;

```
for(i=0;i<M;i++) {
   if (pthread_create(&thr_id[i], NULL, Generiraj, new int(i)) != 0) {
      cout<<"Greska pri stvaranju dretve!\n";
      exit(1);
   }
}

void *Generiraj(void * ptr){
    int i = *(int*)ptr;
    delete   (int*)ptr;

    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        ZajednickoPolje[i][j]=rand()%50;

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I get the error "warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]"

Comment: Yeah, now it's working, thanks a lot! I just don't understand now why do I get all values 0, gotta fix it

Comment: Got it working, thanks a lot again! Wow, didn't know I will get answers this fast

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving the address of the variable i, if i changes outside, variable i used by your threads also changes, when your thread wants to access i, it has already reached the value of 2*M in the for loops. So, you should give the parameter i as a different pointer which points to the same value as i (so many i's).

Comment: You can go without brackets, because there is only 1 if in loop, and if has it's own brackets

Comment: it's not being passed by reference, rather a pointer to it is passed to `pthread_create` which has the same effect. Unfortunately the `pthread_create` function expects a `void*` for user data, you cannot pass by value!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a set of steps (one approach at least)

1. Construct an array like you do for thread ids, which will hold the values of `i` for each thread
2. Pass the corresponding entry from this array rather than `&i` to the thread